# Pass parameters to Models in Laravel

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel, laravel-4

I'm new in Laravel I need help in passing variables to models/model methods

In codeigniter I do this

```
$this->model_name->model_method($variable_name);
```

How can I translate this in Laravel syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 4 uses exactly the same syntax, but methods are camel cased:

```
$this->model_name->modelMethod($variable_name);
```

Taking from the comments, this is how you should be doing your scopes:

```
public function scopeTestMethod($query, $user) 
{ 
    return $query->where('user', $user); 
}
```

To

```
$posts = Post::TestMethod($user)->get();
```

or

```
$test = Post::query(); 

$test = $test->TestMethod($user)->get();
```

Take a look at the Laravel docs: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes

Comment: Hi antonio thanks for replying, I tried using that and Im just getting an error

example:

Model 

function scopeTest_method() {
    
        return DB::table('db_name')->where('user', $user)->get();

}

How can I pass the $user variable from my Controller?

I tried 

$test = new test();

$test = $test->Test_method($user);

but im also getting an error even if I use the one you posted still error.

Comment: Im using laravel 4 if thats relevant

Comment: You should add all relevant information on your question. Just edited to show how you do and use scopes.

Comment: Hi Thanks Antonio, it worked. If you dont mind me asking, where can I find docs in regards with what you posted? I cant seem to find it Laravel docs. In CI docs example the Active Query - it shows the CI syntax and the procedural counterpart. Is there anything like that in Laravel?

Comment: On the Laravel website there's all the basic info you need.

Comment: Laravel's ORM is called Eloquent, as Antonio linked in his answer. Everything you want to know about Models is found on that Doc page.